ASP.NET Get PrintTicket from remote Print-Server
I've been on this problem for a while now and I can't seem to find an answer.
I want to get the PrintTicket from a specific printer on a server and then distribute this ticket to other print servers.
Right now I solved this with a powershell script, but I want to migrate everything to C#.
What I tried so far without success:
From the docs I read that the System.Printing namespace are not valid on ASP.NET Webapplications, but I gave it a try anyways. But it throws an MS.Utility.EventTrace error. So I guess that won't work.
string sPrinterName = "printerOnServer";
string sServerName = "serverName";
PrintServer server = new PrintServer($@"\\{sServerName}");
var ticket = server.GetPrintQueue(sPrinterName).DefaultPrintTicket.Clone(); //Throws the error here
var stream = ticket.GetXmlStream();

From the Win32_Printer class with WMI, you can't get access to the ticket in anyway. I hope to find a solution here or any hints how I could solve it.
For reference the powershell script is like that:
$GPC = get-printconfiguration -PrinterName \\$PrintServer\$PrinterName
$GPC.PrintTicketXML | out-file $FilePath
$XMLA = Get-Content $FilePath | Out-String
Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName \\$DifferentPrintServer\$PrinterName -PrintTicketXml $XMLA


For people that have the same problem... I couldn't find an answer to that. So I left it with the powershell script.
